# Accessing string literal in .data section has wrong address

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have a very simple assembly program:

```
global start

section .text
start:
mov r12, string_2

section .data
string_1: db 'string one',0
string_2: db 'string two',0
```

I assemble and link it on my mac with nasm:

`nasm -fmacho64 -o string.o ./string.x64 && ld -o string ./string.o`

And then debug it with `lldb string`.

What I see is that the address loaded into `r12` is not the actual address that `string_2` exists at. `string_1` is placed at address `0x2000`, with `string_2` right after it, beginning at address `0x200b`. But the address loaded into `r12` is `0x2016`. How do I load the actual address of `string_2`?

In case it's relevant, these are the versions of the programs I'm using:

```
$ nasm -v
NASM version 2.13.03 compiled on Feb  8 2018
$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-351.8
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
LTO support using: LLVM version 9.1.0, (clang-902.0.39.1) (static support for 21, runtime is 21)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 9.1.0 (tapi-902.0.9)
$ lldb -v
lldb-902.0.79.2
  Swift-4.1
```

Comment: How about `lea r12, string_2`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: In NASM syntax, that would be `lea r12, [rel string_2]`, because the OP isn't using `default rel`.  But yeah, should work, looks like another macho64 NASM bug, this time with absolute addressing.